# Can not click on Checkout button on new window

Tags: java, selenium, iframe

I am having this strange problem. When checking out from an ecommerce site, i get a iframe. I was able to handle the iFrame with

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

After that iframe, there is another window that comes up. its not a iFrame. I have tried window handle, but nothing working so far. can't seem to click on the checkout button.

```
String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); 
String subWindowHandler = null;

Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
    driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='layer_cart']/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/a/span")).click();

}

driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);
```

this is the HTML code, hope it helps:

```
<div class="button-container">
<span class="continue btn btn-default button exclusive-medium" title="Continue shopping">
**<a class="btn btn-default button button-medium" href="http://website.com/index.php?controller=order" title="Proceed to checkout" rel="nofollow">
<span>
Proceed to checkout
<i class="icon-chevron-right right"></i>
</span>
</a>**
</div>
```

Comment: I Also tried the following:


        String handle= driver.getWindowHandle();
        
        System.out.println(handle);
  driver.switchTo().window(handle);
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-default.button.button-medium>span")).click();

Comment: what's the error that you receive?

Comment: element not found [...]

Comment: If possible share the url

Comment: dear kushal, i believe its not a good idea to share the link in public. is there a way to send a msg? or email? my email is faihasan77@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

to switch to default frame you can use

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

and you better not to use such locators at all, as divs could be replaced at any time, and your locator became invalid : ".//*[@id='layer_cart']/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/a/span"

try something like `".//*[@title='Continue shopping']"`

Comment: its actually in another window, not the defaultContent();        

String handle= driver.getWindowHandle();
        
        System.out.println(handle);
  driver.switchTo().window(handle);
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-default.button.button-medium>span")).click();

Comment: if it helps, every time i am printing the window (handle) i get a dynamic key: 'CDwindow-ead01658-325c-4ce7-a761-951f874a7e0c'